# how to display unicode characters(e.g. chinese,japanese) in java application?

Tags: java

I have tried below code, but only '?' gets printed instead of unicode characters.

```
public static void main(String s[]){
  char i1 = 0x0ABF;
  char i2 = 0x0AFF;
  String str = "A\u0303";
  System.out.println(str);
  System.out.println(i1);
  System.out.println(i2);
}
```

I am using jdk1.6.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've fixed the code formatting in the question for you. Please take a moment to read the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the Ask a Question area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. (There's also a preview box shown under the Ask a Question box where you can preview your question.)

Answer (score 3):

This probably has more to do with the OS you are on. Java handles unicode internally, no problem but once it's written to the stdout, it's up to the console/pipe receiving it to be able to understand and print it on the screen or in the file. Windows console does not support printing unicode characters.